# PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE and PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE concurrent monitoring

Tags: perf, multiplexing, intel-pmu

I'm working on a custom implementation on top of `perf_event_open` syscall.

The implementation aims to support various of `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE`, `PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE` and `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events for **specific threads on any core**.

In *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual vol 3B* I see the following for my testing CPU (Kaby Lake):

[image]

To my understanding so far, one can monitor (theoretically) unlimited `PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE` events concurrently but limited (without multiplexing) `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` and `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events concurrently since each event is measured by the limited (as can be seen on the manual above) number of counters of the CPU's PMU.

So for a quad-core Kaby Lake CPU with HyperThreading enabled I assume that up to 4 `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE`/`PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events can be monitored concurrently (or up to 8 if only 4 threads are used).

Experimenting with the above assumptions I found out that while I can successfully monitor up to 4 `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` events (for 8 threads) this is not the case for `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events where only up to 2 events can be monitored concurrently!

I also tried to use only 4 threads but the upper limit of concurrently monitored 'PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE' events remains 4. The same is happening with HyperThreading **disabled**!

One could ask: why do you need to avoid multiplexing. First of all, the implementation needs to be as much accurate as possible by avoiding the potential blind spots of multiplexing and secondly when the "upper limit" is exceeded all event values are 0...

The `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events I'm targeting are:

```
CACHE_LLC_READ(PERF_HW_CACHE_TYPE_ID.PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_LL.value  | PERF_HW_CACHE_OP_ID.PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ.value << 8 | PERF_HW_CACHE_OP_RESULT_ID.PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_ACCESS.value << 16),
CACHE_LLC_WRITE(PERF_HW_CACHE_TYPE_ID.PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_LL.value  | PERF_HW_CACHE_OP_ID.PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_WRITE.value << 8 | PERF_HW_CACHE_OP_RESULT_ID.PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_ACCESS.value << 16),
CACHE_LLC_READ_MISS(PERF_HW_CACHE_TYPE_ID.PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_LL.value  | PERF_HW_CACHE_OP_ID.PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ.value << 8 | PERF_HW_CACHE_OP_RESULT_ID.PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS.value << 16),
CACHE_LLC_WRITE_MISS(PERF_HW_CACHE_TYPE_ID.PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_LL.value  | PERF_HW_CACHE_OP_ID.PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_WRITE.value << 8 | PERF_HW_CACHE_OP_RESULT_ID.PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS.value << 16),
```

all are implemented with the provided formula:

```
(perf_hw_cache_id) | (perf_hw_cache_op_id << 8) |
(perf_hw_cache_op_result_id << 16)
```

and are manipulated as a group (the first is the group leader etc).

So, my questions are the following:

1. Which counters of the PMU are used for `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` and which for `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events and where can I find this information?
2. What is the difference between the `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` pre-defined events (such as `PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES`) and the `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events?
3. Any suggestions on how to monitor without multiplexing all listed `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events?
4. Any suggestions on how to monitor without multiplexing up to 8 `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` or/and `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` and `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events are mapped to two sets of registers involved in performance monitoring. The first set of MSRs are called `IA32_PERFEVTSELx` where x can vary from 0 to N-1, N being the total number of general purpose counters available. The `PERFEVTSEL` is a short for "performance event select", they specify various conditions on the fulfillment of which event counting will happen. The second set of MSRs are called `IA32_PMCx`, where x varies similarly as `PERFEVTSEL`. These PMC registers store the counts of performance monitoring events. Each `PERFEVTSEL` register is paired with a corresponding `PMC` register.

The mapping happens as follows-

At the initialization of the architecture specific portion of the kernel, a pmu for measuring hardware specific events is registered [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/arch/x86/events/core.c#L1908) with type `PERF_TYPE_RAW`. All `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` and `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events are mapped to `PERF_TYPE_RAW` events to identify the pmu, as can be seen [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/kernel/events/core.c#L10511).

```
if (type == PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE || type == PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE)
        type = PERF_TYPE_RAW;
```

The same architecture specific initialization is responsible for setting up the addresses of the first/base registers of each of the aforementioned sets of performance monitoring event registers, [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L3950)

```
    .eventsel       = MSR_ARCH_PERFMON_EVENTSEL0,
    .perfctr        = MSR_ARCH_PERFMON_PERFCTR0,
```

The `event_init` function specific to the PMU identified, is responsible for setting up and "reserving" the two sets of performance monitoring registers, as well as checking for event constraints etc., [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/arch/x86/events/core.c#L2350). The reservation happens [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/arch/x86/events/core.c#L148).

```
for (i = 0; i < x86_pmu.num_counters; i++) {
        if (!reserve_perfctr_nmi(x86_pmu_event_addr(i)))
            goto perfctr_fail;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < x86_pmu.num_counters; i++) {
        if (!reserve_evntsel_nmi(x86_pmu_config_addr(i)))
            goto eventsel_fail;
    }
```

The value `num_counters` = number of general-purpose counters as identified by `CPUID` instruction.

In addition to this, there are a couple of extra [registers](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L232) that monitor offcore events (eg. the LLC-cache specific events).

In later versions of architectural performance monitoring, some of the hardware events are measured with the help of fixed-purpose registers, as seen [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L193). These are the fixed-purpose [registers](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/arch/x86/include/asm/perf_event.h#L158) -

```
#define MSR_ARCH_PERFMON_FIXED_CTR0 0x309
#define MSR_ARCH_PERFMON_FIXED_CTR1 0x30a
#define MSR_ARCH_PERFMON_FIXED_CTR2 0x30b
```

2. The `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` pre-defined [events](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L30) are all **architectural** performance monitoring events. These events are architectural, since the behavior of each architectural performance event is expected to be consistent on all processors that support that event. All of the `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events are **non-architectural**, which means they are model-specific and may vary from one family of processors to another.
3. For an Intel Kaby Lake machine that I have, a total of 20 `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events are pre-defined. The event constraints [involved](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L192), ensure that the 3 fixed-function counters available are mapped to 3 `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` architectural events. Only one event can be measured on each of the fixed-function counters, so we can discard them for our analysis. The other constraint is that only two events targeting the LLC-caches, can be measured at the same time, since there are only two `OFFCORE RESPONSE` registers. Also, the `nmi-watchdog` may pin an event to another counter from the family of general-purpose counters. If the `nmi-watchdog` is disabled, we are left with 4 general purpose counters.

Given the constraints involved, and the limited number of counters available, there is just no way to avoid multiplexing if all the 20 hardware cache events are measured at the same time. Some workarounds to measure all the events, without incurring multiplexing and its errors, are -

3.1.  Group all the `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events into groups of 4, such that all of the 4 events can be scheduled on each of the 4 general-purpose counters at the same time. Make sure there are no more than 2 LLC cache events in a group. Run the same profile and obtain the counts for each of the groups separately.

3.2.  If all the `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events are to be monitored at the same time, then some of the errors with multiplexing can be reduced, by decreasing the value of `perf_event_mux_interval_ms`. It can be configured via a sysfs entry called `/sys/devices/cpu/perf_event_mux_interval_ms`. This value cannot be lowered beyond a point, as can be seen [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/kernel/events/core.c#L1112).

4. Monitoring upto 8 hardware or hardware-cache events would require hyperthreading to be disabled. Note that, the information about the number of general purpose counters available are retrieved using the `CPUID` instruction and the number of such counters are setup at the architecture initialization portion of the kernel startup via the `early_initcall` function. This can be seen [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.15/source/kernel/events/core.c#L1112). Once the initialization is done, the kernel understands that only 4 counters are available, and any changes in hyperthreading capabilities later, do not make any difference.

Comment: Amazing answer @Arnabjyoti Kalita! You illuminate aspects of perf which are totally undocumented. Thank you!