# only 2 PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE events in perf event group

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu-cache, perf, intel-pmu

Working on a custom implementation on top of `perf_event_open` I need to monitor multiple `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` concurrently.

The Intel manual states that there are 4 programmable counters per thread (or 8 if HyperThreading is disabled) for my CPU's architecture. So I grouped the `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events of choice into 1 perf event group containing `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` 4 events (`LLC_GROUP`).

I run a first experiment and I got the following results:

```
LLC_GROUP of thread 2 | time Enabled: 3190370379, time Running: 3017
HW_CACHE_LLC_READ_MISSES = 0
HW_CACHE_LLC_WRITE_MISSES = 0
HW_CACHE_LLC_READS = 0
HW_CACHE_LLC_WRITES = 0
```

From the above results, it is clear that the PMU does not "fit" all the 4 events. We also observe a "strange" multiplexing without actual results..

So, as a next move, I split the 4-events group into 2 groups of 2 events/group (`LLC_GROUP`, `LLC2_GROUP`) and the result I got are the following:

```
LLC_GROUP of thread 2 | time Enabled: 2772569406, time Running: 1396022331
HW_CACHE_LLC_READ_MISSES = 102117
HW_CACHE_LLC_WRITE_MISSES = 9624295
LLC2_GROUP of thread 2 | time Enabled: 2772571024, time Running: 1376575096
HW_CACHE_LLC_READS = 22020658
HW_CACHE_LLC_WRITES = 18156060
```

With this configuration, we observe again that the PMU doesn't "fit" 4 `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` concurrently but this time the (expected) multiplexing is happening.

Does anyone have any explanation?

This behaviour looks very strange to me since I'm able to monitor multiple `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` events (up to 6) without multiplexing and I would expect the same to be happening for the `PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE` events as well.

Comment: What CPU and kernel version are you using?  (This looks like a followup to [PERF\_TYPE\_HARDWARE and PERF\_TYPE\_HW\_CACHE concurrent monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61879227), in case that helps anyone trying to answer this.)

Comment: Also, did you disable Linux's NMI watchdog (sysctl `kernel/nmi_watchdog = 0`) to free up the 4th HW perf counter per logical core?

Comment: Hi Peter. Yes indeed, it is sort of a follow-up but more specific I guess... CPU: Kaby Lake, kernel: 4.15.0-74-generic, nmi_watchdog = 0. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, `perf` does allow measuring more than 2 PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE events at the same time, the exception being the measurement of `LLC-cache` events.

The expectation is that, when there are 4 general-purpose and 3 fixed-purpose 
hardware counters, 4 HW cache events (which default to `RAW` events) in perf can be measured without multiplexing, with **hyper-threading ON**.

```
sudo perf stat -e L1-icache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores,L1-dcache-load-misses,dTLB-load-misses sleep 2

 Performance counter stats for 'sleep 2':

            26,893      L1-icache-load-misses                                       
            98,999      L1-dcache-stores                                            
            14,037      L1-dcache-load-misses                                       
               723      dTLB-load-misses                                            

       2.001732771 seconds time elapsed

       0.001217000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys
```

The problem appears when you try to measure events targeting the `LLC-cache`. It seems to be measuring only 2 `LLC-cache` specific events, concurrently, without multiplexing.

```
sudo perf stat -e LLC-load-misses,LLC-stores,LLC-store-misses,LLC-loads sleep 2

 Performance counter stats for 'sleep 2':

             2,419      LLC-load-misses           #    0.00% of all LL-cache hits   
             2,963      LLC-stores                                                  
     <not counted>      LLC-store-misses                                              (0.00%)
     <not counted>      LLC-loads                                                     (0.00%)

       2.001486710 seconds time elapsed

       0.001137000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys
```

CPUs belonging to the `skylake/kaby lake` family of microarchitectures and some others, allow you to measure `OFFCORE RESPONSE` events. Monitoring `OFFCORE_RESPONSE` events requires programming extra MSRs, specifically, `MSR_OFFCORE_RSP0` (MSR address 1A6H)  and `MSR_OFFCORE_RSP1` (MSR address 1A7H), in addition to programming the pair of `IA32_PERFEVTSELx` and `IA32_PMCx` registers.

Each pair of `IA32_PERFEVTSELx` and `IA32_PMCx` register will be associated with one of the above MSRs to measure LLC-cache events.

The definition of the `OFFCORE_RESPONSE` MSRs can be seen [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L229).

```
static struct extra_reg intel_skl_extra_regs[] __read_mostly = {
    INTEL_UEVENT_EXTRA_REG(0x01b7, MSR_OFFCORE_RSP_0, 0x3fffff8fffull, RSP_0),
    INTEL_UEVENT_EXTRA_REG(0x01bb, MSR_OFFCORE_RSP_1, 0x3fffff8fffull, RSP_1),
    ........
}
```

`0x01b7` in the `INTEL_UEVENT_EXTRA_REG` call refers to event-code `b7` and umask `01`. This event code `0x01b7` maps to LLC-cache events, as can be seen [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L417) -

```
[ C(LL  ) ] = {
    [ C(OP_READ) ] = {
        [ C(RESULT_ACCESS) ] = 0x1b7,   /* OFFCORE_RESPONSE */
        [ C(RESULT_MISS)   ] = 0x1b7,   /* OFFCORE_RESPONSE */
    },
    [ C(OP_WRITE) ] = {
        [ C(RESULT_ACCESS) ] = 0x1b7,   /* OFFCORE_RESPONSE */
        [ C(RESULT_MISS)   ] = 0x1b7,   /* OFFCORE_RESPONSE */
    },
    [ C(OP_PREFETCH) ] = {
        [ C(RESULT_ACCESS) ] = 0x0,
        [ C(RESULT_MISS)   ] = 0x0,
    },
 },
```

The event `0x01b7` will always map to `MSR_OFFCORE_RSP_0`, as can be seen [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/arch/x86/events/core.c#L113). The function, specified above, loops through the array of all the "extra registers" and associates the event->config(which contains the raw event id) with the offcore response MSR.

So, this would mean only one event can be measured at a time, since only one MSR - `MSR_OFFCORE_RSP_0` can be mapped to a `LLC-cache` event. But, that is not the case!

The offcore registers are symmetric in nature, so when the first MSR - `MSR_OFFCORE_RSP_0` register is busy, `perf` uses the second alternative MSR, `MSR_OFFCORE_RSP_1` for measuring another offcore LLC event. This function [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L2355) helps in doing that.

```
static int intel_alt_er(int idx, u64 config)
{
    int alt_idx = idx;

    if (!(x86_pmu.flags & PMU_FL_HAS_RSP_1))
        return idx;

    if (idx == EXTRA_REG_RSP_0)
        alt_idx = EXTRA_REG_RSP_1;

    if (idx == EXTRA_REG_RSP_1)
        alt_idx = EXTRA_REG_RSP_0;

    if (config & ~x86_pmu.extra_regs[alt_idx].valid_mask)
        return idx;

    return alt_idx;
}
```

The presence of only 2 offcore registers, for `Kaby-Lake` family of microrarchitectures hinder the ability to target more than 2 LLC-cache event measurement concurrently, without any multiplexing.